# How to change the default directory for Open Project menu in Spyder?

Tags: python, user-interface, project, spyder

How can I change the default directory in Spyder when opening a project via Projects > Open Project? Spyder seems to open always the same directory: User Home directory.

Most of my projects are located in one directory, which is not my home directory. I save there also the copied projects. It would save a few clicks to open a project. In particular, it is nice to have because the number of Recent Projects is limited to 10.

I tried to change Preferences > Current working directory > the following directory, but this does not have any impact on the Open Project directory.

Is there a possibility to change it either in GUI, or via configuration files, or registry (without changing the user home directory of course)?

Comment: I don't think you can change that... If I'm looking at the right places, it seems the [`open_project()`](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/v4.0.0rc1/spyder/plugins/projects/plugin.py#L278) function always takes [`get_home_dir()`](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/v4.0.0rc1/spyder/config/base.py#L153) as its base directory, which is essentially wherever `~` gets you (you cannot even override it with `HOME` or anything, since it checks for `~` first, which should work in Unix and Windows). You may file an issue proposing the feature for the developer's consideration, though.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no way to do that, but I don't understand why you want to be able to do it. Please edit your answer to elaborate about it.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I clarified the question. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: Ok, I understand your use case better now. Please open an issue [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues), so we don't forget to address it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I put a shortcut in my home directory called `_shortcut_to_spyder_projects` to get to my projects faster.  The leading `_` keeps it at the top of the list.